# How to prove $|x − y| ≤ |x| + |y|$, proof and reasoning

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Prove that, for all $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}$, we have $|x − y| ≤ |x| + |y|$.
Can I say . $|x − y|^2 ≤ (x − y)^2$, and work from there?
Thank you

Comment: How exactly do you plan to work from $|x − y|^2 ≤ (x − y)^2$ to the inequality to be proved?

Comment: In fact $|x-y|^2=(x-y)^2$, so nothing to gain from that. If you're familiar with the triangle inequality, this actually *is* the triangle inequality for $x$ and $-y$, since $|-y|=|y|$.

Comment: so does it follow to say |x − y|=|x + (-y)|≤ |x|+|-y|...

Comment: @omm: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.
Consider by contradiction that $|x-y| > |x| + |y|$. Then, multiplying both sides by $|x-y|$, we have that 
$$|x-y|^2 > (|x| + |y|)(|x-y|)$$
$$(x-y)^2 > (|x| + |y|)(|x-y|).$$
So we have that 
$$ x^2 - 2xy + y^2 > (|x| + |y|)(|x-y|) > (|x| + |y|)(|x| + |y|), $$
by assumption. It follows that
$$ x^2 - 2xy + y^2 > |x|^2 + 2|x||y| + |y|^2 $$
$$ x^2 - 2xy + y^2 > x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2 $$
$$ -xy > |x||y| $$
which is a contradiction. So, we have that $|x-y| \leq |x| + |y|$, as required.